# How to filter an object that has nested arrays by the second nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, typescript

I have an object with a structure like below.

```
Object{
    Array [{
        property1: "",
        property2: "",
        innerArray: [{
            arrayProperty1
            arrayProperty2
          }]
    }]
}
```

What is the best by way to filter by innerArray.Property2? I have a list of filters I need to apply. The code below is how I'm currently attempting to apply the filters, however the list is not being altered at all.

```
    if(filterList)
    {
      // if this length is 0, don't include inventory in the filter
      let filterOnInventoryId = filterList.filter((item: any) => {
        return (item && item.Type === 'InventoryId');
      });


      let shouldFilterInventoryId = filterOnInventoryId && filterOnInventoryId.length > 0;
      let shouldFilterAppointmentType = filterOnAppointmentType && filterOnAppointmentType.length > 0;

      // find any inventoryIds that are part of the filter, else return an empty list
      let filteredListInventoryId = shouldFilterInventoryId ? filterOnInventoryId.filter((item: any) => 
      {
        var x = this.selectedDateAndAppointmentList.filter((dateModelAndAppointment: any) => 
        {
          return dateModelAndAppointment.appointmentList.filter((appointment: any) =>{
            item.InventoryTypeId == appointment.Inventory.InventoryTypeId;
          })
        })
        return x;
      }) : [];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesting array filtering such as:

```
selectedDateAndAppointmentList.filter(dateModelAndAppointment =>
  dateModelAndAppointment.appointmentList.filter(...)
);
```

will not perform any filtering of the top array because `Array.prototype.filter` always returns an array and your code is thus filtering on the truthy-ness of `[]`, which is always truthy, and nothing gets filtered.

```
selectedDateAndAppointmentList.filter(dateModelAndAppointment =>
  dateModelAndAppointment.appointmentList.filter(...)
  // ^ will always return true because appointmentList.filter always returns an array
);
```

Here's what's happening:

```js
// no filtering is happening because inner
// filter always returns a truthy value
console.log(
  [{ values: ["a", "b"] }, { values: ["c", "d"] }].filter(item =>
    item.values.filter(val => val === "a")
  )
);
```

Instead, you should use `Array.prototype.some` or `Array.prototype.every` which return a boolean and not an array and thus can be used as a filtering condition:

```
selectedDateAndAppointmentList.filter(dateModelAndAppointment => 
  dateModelAndAppointment.appointmentList.some(...)
  // ^ this will return a boolean based on a nested array condition
)
```

For example:

```js
// filtering now works because the inner filter
// correctly returns a boolean value depending 
// on the filter condition
console.log(
  [{ values: ["a", "b"] }, { values: ["c", "d"] }].filter(item =>
    item.values.some(val => val === "a")
  )
);
```